# GeoServer MBStyles extension: No layer or layer group named 'x' found in the catalog

Tags: geoserver, style

I'm an absolute beginner with geoserver, but set up a tileserver-gl-light server with some styles from [github](https://github.com/openmaptiles/maptiler-basic-gl-style) and it looks pretty. On the other side, our team has a running geoserver that works but doesn't look so good. Thus, we want to style the geoserver map using the mapbox style from github.

We have the MBStyles extension installed on the geoserver, but when I copied the [style.json](https://github.com/openmaptiles/maptiler-basic-gl-style/blob/master/style.json) into the geoserver new style editor and hit the validate button; it gives a dozen errors:

```
Layer background:This layer is not meant to be transformed, but converted in a Style background fill
No layer or layer group named 'landuse' found in the catalog
No layer or layer group named 'landcover' found in the catalog
No layer or layer group named 'water' found in the catalog
No layer or layer group named 'landcover' found in the catalog
No layer or layer group named 'waterway' found in the catalog
No layer or layer group named 'transportation' found in the catalog
No layer or layer group named 'building' found in the catalog
No layer or layer group named 'housenumber' found in the catalog
No layer or layer group named 'transportation' found in the catalog
No layer or layer group named 'aeroway' found in the catalog
No layer or layer group named 'transportation' found in the catalog
No layer or layer group named 'waterway' found in the catalog
No layer or layer group named 'transportation' found in the catalog
No layer or layer group named 'boundary' found in the catalog
No layer or layer group named 'aerodrome_label' found in the catalog
No layer or layer group named 'transportation_name' found in the catalog
No layer or layer group named 'place' found in the catalog
```

I have no idea about the first one. The second(similar to the rest) complains that it cannot find the layer or layer group 'landuse'. The 'landuse' layer is referenced by other 'landuse-' layers as a "source-layer":

```
"source-layer": "landuse"
```

I tried putting it up before its usage but that didn't help.

What should I do with the "source-layer"s in the mapbox style?

Comment: It feels like you have only the rendering styles on your computer but not the data. Maybe you should have a look at https://github.com/geosolutions-it/osm-styles for better understanding the concept.

Comment: @user30184 We have the data as I mentioned, but the current style is not so good. I'm going to create another layer with the data after I added this style.